# Linq to Get distinct List of rows in descending order

Tags: entity-framework, linq

Consider following record

```
  Id            F1            F2     f3         Date 
 -------------------------------------------------
   1           1800          1990     19      2016-06-27 09:24:25.550
   2           1181          1991     19      2016-06-27 09:25:15.243
   3           1919          2000     19      2016-06-27 11:04:27.807
   4           1920          2000     19      2016-06-27 13:04:27.807
   5           1800          2001     19      2016-06-28 09:24:25.550
   6           1181          2002     19      2016-06-28 09:25:15.243 
   7           1919          2010     19      2016-06-28 11:04:27.807
```

I want to Groupby f1 sorted by Date descending 
Desirder Output

```
      Id            F1           F2    f3         Date 
     -------------------------------------------------
      7           1919          2010     19      2016-06-28 11:04:27.807    
      6           1181          2002     19      2016-06-28 09:25:15.243        
      5           1800          2001     19      2016-06-28 09:24:25.550
      4           1920          2000     19      2016-06-27 13:04:27.807
```

I have Tried with

```
    DateTime EndDate=DateTime.Now.AddDays(-1);
     var result = (from opt in db.Output
                                     where opt.f3==19 && opt.Date > EndDate
                                     orderby opt.Date descending
                                     select new 
                                     {
                                         Id= opt.Id,
                                         F1=opt.F1,
                                         F2=opt.F2,
                                         F3=opt.F3,
                                         Date=opt.Date
                                     }).GroupBy(x => x.F1).Select(s => s.OrderBy(o => o.F2).FirstOrDefault()).OrderByDescending(x => x.Date).ToList();
```

Im getting Output as

```
 Id            F1            F2     f3         Date 
 -------------------------------------------------
   1           1800          1990     19      2016-06-27 09:24:25.550
   2           1181          1991     19      2016-06-27 09:25:15.243
   3           1919          2000     19      2016-06-27 11:04:27.807
   4           1920          2000     19      2016-06-27 13:04:27.807
```

What is wrong with my code.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly you want the most recent item of each group:

```
db.Output.GroupBy(opt => opt.F1).
          Select(group => group.OrderByDescending(opt => opt.Date).First()).
          OrderBy(opt => opt.ID);
```

I'm not sure the translation to SQL with be efficient though due to the inner ordering.

Now since [GroupBy preserves order](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb534304.aspx), you might fix this issue with:

```
db.Output.OrderByDescending(opt => opt.Date).
          GroupBy(opt => opt.F1).
          Select(group => group.First().
          OrderBy(opt => opt.ID);
```

Comment: I have tried with this code also but output is same.

Comment: Are you getting opt #1? If so it is weird, what's the type of Date?

Comment: Date is of DateTime type.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is in `s.OrderBy(o => o.F2).FirstOrDefault()`. Here ordering should be on `Date`.

Why your code doesn't work :

```
//creates group
.GroupBy(x => x.F1)
//Order by F1 and take first - *Here the record with latest date is eliminated
.Select(s => s.OrderBy(o => o.F2).FirstOrDefault())
//This order by desc is of no use as we already have only 1 rec from each group
.OrderByDescending(x => x.Date).ToList();
```

---

```
var result = db.Output
              .Where(opt => opt.f3==19 && opt.Date > EndDate)
              .OrderByDescending(o => o.Date)
              .GroupBy(x => x.F1)
              .Select(s => s.FirstOrDefault())
              .ToList();
```

or

```
var result = db.Output
              .Where(opt => opt.f3==19 && opt.Date > EndDate)
              .OrderBy(o1=>o1.F2)
              .ThenByDescending(o => o.Date)
              .GroupBy(x => x.F1)
              .Select(s => s.FirstOrDefault())
              .ToList();
```

Answer (score 0):

Use Multiple column Group

```
 DateTime EndDate=DateTime.Now.AddDays(-1);
         var result = (from opt in db.Output
                                         where opt.f3==19 && opt.Date > EndDate
                                         orderby opt.Date descending
                                         select new 
                                         {
                                             Id= opt.Id,
                                             F1=opt.F1,
                                             F2=opt.F2,
                                             F3=opt.F3,
                                             Date=opt.Date
                                         }).GroupBy(x => new{x.Date, x.F1}).Select(s => s.OrderBy(o => o.F2).FirstOrDefault()).OrderByDescending(x => x.Date).ToList();
```